# Setting RavenDB license for automated deployment in kubernetes

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to deploy a RavenDB instance on a Kubernetes cluster. The deployment should be fully automated, i.e. there should be no need to access the UI to configure something.

I have found plenty of documentation on how raven in a container can be configured, e.g. with command line args via `RAVEN_ARGS`, environment variables (e.g. `RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted`), or a custom `settings.json` file in a mounted volume.

I have tried all the options above, and they all work, except when trying to set a license. I have tried to set either `License` directly as a JSON string or `License.Path` pointing to a `license.json` file mounted in a volume. Yet whenever I access the UI after deploying the container, I get a notification telling me I need to set a license.

Can anyone tell me how I can get Raven to use the license I provide via the approaches mentioned above?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bootstrap the cluster with some kind of operation for the license to be picked up. For example, create a database or call the /admin/cluster/bootstrap endpoint.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me.

`{"Url":"/admin/cluster/bootstrap","Type":"Raven.Client.Exceptions.Routing.RouteNotFoundException","Message":"There is no handler for path: GET /admin/cluster/bootstrap" .... RavenDB-Stable-5.4\\54032...`